# Code sign .msi and .exe using microsoft authenticode certificate from verisign

Tags: code-signing, code-signing-certificate, verisign

I ordered a verisign code signing certificate (microsoft authenticode) and I now have a .cer file that has my certificate.

I have checked the signtool.exe documentation and I now require a .pfx file. How do I get the .pfx file and how do I get my private key (.pvk file)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you get this file from verisign on any other provider. 
they usually install the certificate on your machine and you need to export it as pfx to use it with signtool.

Use MMC and add the Certificate snap-in to do it.

You will find a detailed help in your certificate provider site. make sure you've bought a code signing certificate.

Comment: and where do I get the .pvk from?

Comment: When i try to export the certificate using IE or snap-in, the .pfx option is greyed out.

Comment: then you have a problem in the installed certificate.

Comment: you should get instruction from the provider of the certificate - if you have a private key and you check the box "include private key" it should save as PFX. you don't need anything else.